# Pandas - How to fill a mostly empty column with the most recent value, up to the next different value?

Tags: python, pandas

By example, suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Index   A   B   C   Type
    0   5   1   4      a
    1   4   1  23
    2   1   4   5
    3  16   2  19      c
    4   3   4   5
    5   8   2   4
    6   3   3   3
    7   0   9   2    b-2
    8   3   2   1
    9   1   0   5
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Index   A   B   C   Type
    0   5   1   4      a
    1   4   1  23      a
    2   1   4   5      a
    3  16   2  19      c
    4   3   4   5      c
    5   8   2   4      c
    6   3   3   3      c
    7   0   9   2    b-2
    8   3   2   1    b-2
    9   1   0   5    b-2
```

`A`, `B`, and `C` are numbers and `Type` is always a string. The amount of data between different types is never constant, and the type doesn't follow any pattern. When the type changes in the experiment, it's just tagged on a single line in the .csv where this data comes from.

I suppose I could iterate through every row in the dataframe and look for where `Type` is not `''` and do some tricky logic to fill subsequent rows until I encounter a new value, but I'm looking for a fast, vectorized solution. The actual data is often >100k lines and we have dozens of files.

Comment: What are in the empty cells? The empty strings? If so, `df['Type'] = df['Type'].where(df['Type'].ne('')).ffill()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fillna`:

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: This is good, but Quang's comment wraps up 1) the empty strings that the column is currently populated with and 2) the FutureWarning that (method='ffill') is moving to .ffill().